# Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction java error

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I need call another web service from my java code. So i write following code.

```
    QName serviceQName = new QName(targetNamespace, webserviceName);
    QName portQName = new QName(targetNamespace, portName);

    Service service = Service.create(serviceQName);
    service.addPort(portQName, SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING, endpointUrl);
    Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch = service.createDispatch(portQName, SOAPMessage.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);

    SOAPMessage sOAPMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart sOAPPart = sOAPMessage.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope sOAPEnvelope = sOAPPart.getEnvelope();
    SOAPBody sOAPBody = sOAPEnvelope.getBody();
    Document bodyDocument = XmlUtil.createDocument(operationName, targetNamespace, "pre");
        bodyDocument = XmlUtil.wrapDocument(bodyDocument, parameterDocument);
    }
    sOAPBody.addDocument(bodyDocument);

    MimeHeaders headers = sOAPMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", targetNamespace + operationName);

    // calling SOAP webservice operation
    SOAPMessage response = dispatch.invoke(sOAPMessage);

    Object resultObj = JAXBUtil.unmarshalFromNode(resultNode, resultObjectUnmarshallerClasses);
    return resultObj;
```

And I am added SOAPAction header like this

```
MimeHeaders headers = sOAPMessage.getMimeHeaders();
headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", targetNamespace + operationName);
```

But when I call it it's throwing exception. What's wrong.

**Exception is**: Client received SOAP Fault from server: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: